# Cryptic Error When Attempted to Sign Kernel Modules

Tags: kernel, module

I have a Debian 10 system. It has secure boot enabled. I am trying to sign and load a new kernel module for virtualbox.
I generated a certificate and private key using `openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -days 36500 -subj "/CN=My Name/" -nodes`. Then I imported this key with `mokutil --import MOK.der`. I then entered some password, rebooted, and enrolled the key. Then, after reading dozens of inaccurate tutorials, including Debian.org's OWN tutorial, they all suggested to use a program called `sign-file`. However, `sign-file` was completely missing, and a recursive search of every directory of the system returned nothing. After browsing a few obscure forums, I found a tool called `sbsign`, which seems to be the only available option for signing anything. Any time I attempt to sign a module with it, using the command `sbsign --cert ~/MOK.pem --key ~/MOK.priv /lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/misc/vboxdrv.ko`. However, this command returns `Invalid DOS Header Magic`. There are almost no references to this error anywhere on the internet, and none that relate to my specific problem in any meaningful way.

What does this error mean? What can I do to sign these modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sbsign` is for signing `.efi` binaries and other PE32(+) formatted executables.

`sign-file` comes along with the kernel source code (in the `scripts` directory of the source code tarball) and in the `linux-kbuild-4.19` .deb package for Debian 10. It signs ELF-formatted binary files, which is what Linux kernel modules are.

You cannot substitute one for the other, as the file formats are different.

In situations where you know the exact name of the tool you need but not the name of the package it's in, you should go to the distribution's package contents search engine (good distributions have one). Here's it for Debian: https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages

Scroll down to **Search the contents of packages**, type in "sign-file" to the Keyword field, click on Search and if the file exists in any package of that distribution, you *will* find it.